# How to keep only desired texts "Before and After" in Notepadd + ? Remove all other texts

Tags: jquery, notepad++, ocr, notepad, data-entry

I have some HTML files. How can I remove all texts before and after class="header" or id="header" attribute.
I want to extract all classes like it. For eg:

```
**These are my HTML codes:**

<div class="row">
<div class="header">
<div class="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="footer">

**I want to make abode HTML like:**

class="row"
class="header"
class="navigation"
class="container"
class="footer"
```

Here keeping my desired texts before and after, and removing all other texts. So what I can do? Anybody can help me.. ?

Comment: In visual code you can push alt and click on the lines you want to modify at the same time, in Notepad ++ I think it is called column select or something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    <\S+ (class=".*?")>
Replace: $1
```

This would capture the `class` attribute along with its RHS value, and then replace with just this captured quantity.

### Demo

Comment: Super. Can I do it in my Notepad ++ ? I don't know about "regex mode".

Comment: Yes, in fact you only have to choose replace from the drop down menu, and make sure that regex mode is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Hold shift and alt and use the mouse to select a vertical portion of text. This will do the trick for the begining.

Comment: It looks like you are suggesting doing a block select to remove `<div ` from the start of each line.  Good idea, but what about the closing `>` at the end of each line, all of which are in different columns?

Comment: Yes, it's the problem I don't know about regexp in Notepad++, I think it's better solution :)